# find a function with regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've got some problem to find the  "options" in a jquery ui widget  file with python regex. I read file with "os"  class and put it in a var.

Problem is (I think) tabulation, space and endline caracter.

I try something like:

```
resp = re.findall( r'options\s?:\s?\{.×\n\t×},',  myfile, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL )

(the × symbol for multiplicator symbol)
```

to find the `options{
                         kA: vA,
                         kB : vB,
                         ...etc....
                     }`
 object in the widget.

But it doesn't work. It always put the rest of file at the end of result or find nothing (if i try to change the regex). If I put the last word of the object, it work!
But any other test fail.

Someone have an idea?!

thanks and, have a good new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
/^\s*options{[^}]*}/mg

# explanation:
^ assert position at start of a line
\s* match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
options{ matches the characters options{ literally (case sensitive)
[^}]* match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
} the literal character }
} matches the character } literally
```

Demo:

```
import re

txt='''\
nothing(blah)

options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }
   options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }    

blah blah
    options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }  # tab'''

print(re.findall(r'^\s*(options{[^}]*})',txt, re.S | re.M))
# ['options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }', 'options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }', 'options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }']
```

The more robust solution is to actually parse the file. The regex can be combined with something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) for a better solution:

```
import re
import pyparsing as pp

txt='''\
nothing(blah)

options{ kA: vA, kB : vB}
   options{ kA: vA, kB : vB}    

blah blah
    options{ kA: vA, kB : vB }  # tab
options{
    kA: vA,
    kB: vB,
    kC     :    vC
    }    


    '''

ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas+"_", pp.alphanums+"_")    
comma = pp.Suppress(',')
pair=ident+pp.Suppress(':')+ident    
pair_list=pp.OneOrMore(pair)+pp.ZeroOrMore(comma+pair)    
options=(pp.Suppress('{')+
         pair_list+
         pp.Suppress('}'))

for om in (m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r'^\s*options({[^}]*})',txt, re.S | re.M)):
    res=options.parseString(om)
    data=dict(res[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(res),2))
    print('"{}"=>{}==>{}'.format(om,res,data))
```

Prints:

```
"{ kA: vA, kB : vB}"=>['kA', 'vA', 'kB', 'vB']==>{'kB': 'vB', 'kA': 'vA'}
"{ kA: vA, kB : vB}"=>['kA', 'vA', 'kB', 'vB']==>{'kB': 'vB', 'kA': 'vA'}
"{ kA: vA, kB : vB }"=>['kA', 'vA', 'kB', 'vB']==>{'kB': 'vB', 'kA': 'vA'}
"{
    kA: vA,
    kB: vB,
    kC     :    vC
    }"=>['kA', 'vA', 'kB', 'vB', 'kC', 'vC']==>{'kC': 'vC', 'kB': 'vB', 'kA': 'vA'}
```

Properly parsing takes care of all the whitespace for you and validates in one step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This work really like a charm! Now I know that i'm still noob with regex and got to learn more about this powerfull tool! Gonna check pyparsing too! I try to get other piece of code in my widget (private/public function).. Don't know if it is really robust to check every tabulation, but to find it in my widget, I check number of tabulation (every function/method have 2 tabs ).. ok, we have to indent our code very well, but it seems to work fine if I remove the re.DOTALL. Do you think it can be clean to do this way? Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: The `re.S` that I have is the same as `re.DOTALL`, so yes -- you need that to match a multiline match in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample `"options{ kA: vA, kB : vB, ...etc.... }"`, a rough regex is

```
 #  r'options\s*\{(?:[^:]*:[^,]*(?:,[^:]*:[^,]*)*[,\s]*)?\}'

 options \s* 
 \{
 (?:
      [^:]* : [^,]* 
      (?: , [^:]* : [^,]* )*
      [,\s]* 
 )?
 \}
```